# confused about looping through lists in python

Tags: python, list, loops, slice

Dear StackOverFlow, 
    I just starting learning python, and I'm a little confused when it comes to looping through lists. I have been using Python.org's official python tutorial to learn. In section 4.2 on this page https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html, in the last example they write this code:

```
for w in words[:]:
    if len(w) > 6:
        words.insert(0, w)
```

The part that confuses me is `for w in words[:]:` Maybe I need to read their description a little better, but I can't seem to figure out why
the previous code works and this doesn't:`for w in words:`. I guess it confuses me because when i type **words[:]** in the interpreter I get the same result when i type **words** in the interpreter. If you could shed some light on this topic, I would be very grateful.

Comment: `words[:]` creates a *copy* of the list. It is a new, distinct object. It won't change when you insert into the original list. See [How to clone or copy a list in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2612802)

Comment: I would clarify that its length and the addresses it points to won't change, but the overall contents may change if the copied `list` contains other mutable objects (like `list`s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `for` loop, you're inserting elements into the `words` list. If you iterate directly over the `words` list, the elements that you insert are going to affect the iteration. In general, when modifying a list that you're iterating over, you might get an incorrect result, an exception might be raised, or you could even have an infinite loop as the list grows until you run out of memory.

In your particular case, if there's any `w` in the list for which `len(w) > 6`, you're going to get an infinite loop. Say you have the list `word = ['len(this) == 15']`. In the first iteration, since `len(w) > 6`, it's going to insert `w` at position 0 of `words`, therefore pushing everything else in the list forward. So now `words` is equal to `['len(this) == 15', 'len(this) == 15']`. Now the `for` loop checks to see if there's a next element; there's guaranteed to be, because you just inserted an element at position 0, so the `for` loop iterates again. Of course, `w` contains the same value it did in the last iteration, so the same thing happens. To infinity, and beyond!

Comment: Thanks alot! I think I understand it now. So I iterate through the copy of the list but modify the original list, so I don't affect the iteration process potentially creating an infinite loop or causing an exception. Thanks for the help kind sir.

Comment: @yoprogrammer, you're welcome. If you could upvote as well, I'd appreciate it :). It's [the SO way](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: definitely will upvote, but I seem to be having an issue doing so. As soon as I upvote your post it automatically downvotes it back to zero. Not sure why it's doing this...